# SQlite Query to retrieve the contact which numerical digits are greater 7 and less than 15. Excluding all the special characters

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Can any one help me out for writing a query in SQlite. 
I want to retrive the contact list from native with number size > 7 and number size < 15

1. 92 78 56
2. (987)6543215
3. 987-456-123320201
4. +321456

In the above numbers. I want only 2. rest I do not want in my list.

Normally we can write

```
"length(" + Phone.NUMBER + ") >= 7 and length(" + Phone.NUMBER + ") <= 15"
```

1. `987-456-123320201` will not be displayed and `+321456` will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
// To Retrive the data from database 
    public ArrayList<Integer> getdata(String table) 
    {
    ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int number=0;
        Cursor c= sdb.rawQuery("select * from "+table+"", null);
      if(c!=null)
        {
          while(c.moveToFirst())
          {
                number=c.getInt(0);// 0 represtnt here column name
                int length = (int) Math.log10(number) + 1;
                if(length>7 && lenth<15)
                {
                  al.add(number);
                }
            }   
        }
       return al;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i don't want to maintain the cache(al). I want to retrieve the list directly into cursor object and use CursorLoader to display.

Comment: al is object of arraylist, which wil store ur numbers

Comment: I dont want to maintain any array of objects. I know it by using the arraylist object we can achieve. I want it by the Cursor. Why should i create a arraylist object.I want to optimize the code.